# Gson.toJson() vs JSONObject.toString()

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, tostring

Will #1 and #2 always produce the same output?
What are the advantages of using one solution over the other one?

Solution #2 looks cleaner and simpler to me, is it faster also?

Solution one:

```
val gson = Gson()
val j = JsonObject() //com.google.gson
j.add("foo", gson.fromJson(getBar(), JsonElement::class.java))
val jString = gson.toJson(j)
Log.d(TAG,jString)
```

Solution two:

```
val j1 = JSONObject() //org.json
j1.put("foo", getBar())
val jString1 = j1.toString()
Log.d(TAG,jString1)


fun getBar() : String {
    //do stuff and return a string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) is already included on Android API. If you want to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), you will have to import it as a gradle dependency.

```
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:<versionNumber>'
```

Of course, the more things you import, the bigger your .apk gets.

On the other hand, GSon feeds you with a series of annotations, which makes easier the DX since you have to write less code.

I never benchmarked them, so I won't say a thing about performance, but I do believe both of them benefits from [JsonObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) underneath which comes from Java.

Both [Gson.toJson()](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type-) and [JSONObjet.toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#toString()) have the same effect. They map your JSON object and return to you as a String.